# cannot get DateDiff of date deleted and Now() in vbscript

Tags: arrays, vbscript, datediff, type-mismatch

I am trying to create a vbscript that automatically clears files/folders from the recycle bin that have been there for more than x days. the problem is, when I get the deletion date of the files, the DateDiff function returns a mismatch error.

```
    const Active = TRUE
    const MaxAge = 30
    const RECYCLE_BIN = &Ha&

    checked = 0
    deleted = 0

    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(RECYCLE_BIN)
    Set colItems = objFolder.Items

    For Each objItem  In colItems
            Checked = Checked + 1
            dateDeleted = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objItem, 2) 'the deletion date per file/folder
            If DateDiff("D", dateDeleted, Now()) > MaxAge Then
                    If objItem.Type = "File Folder" Then
                            Deleted = Deleted + 1
                            objFso.DeleteFolder(objItem.Path)
                    Else
                            Deleted = Deleted + 1
                            objFso.DeleteFile(objItem.Path)
                    End If
            End If
    Next
    if Active then verb = " file(s) deleted" Else verb = " file(s) would be deleted"
    WScript.Echo Checked & " file(s) checked, " & Deleted & verb
```

I have also tried doing this but this also returned to mismatch error:

```
    const Active = TRUE
    const MaxAge = 30
    const RECYCLE_BIN = &Ha&

    checked = 0
    deleted = 0

    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(RECYCLE_BIN)
    Set colItems = objFolder.Items

    For Each objItem  In colItems
            Checked = Checked + 1
            dateStr = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objItem, 2) 'the deletion date per file/folder
            dateArr = Split(dateStr, " ")

            If DateDiff("D", dateArr(0), Now()) > MaxAge Then
                    If objItem.Type = "File Folder" Then
                            Deleted = Deleted + 1
                            objFso.DeleteFolder(objItem.Path)
                    Else
                            Deleted = Deleted + 1
                            objFso.DeleteFile(objItem.Path)
                    End If
            End If
    Next
    if Active then verb = " file(s) deleted" Else verb = " file(s) would be deleted"
    WScript.Echo Checked & " file(s) checked, " & Deleted & verb
```

AND tried:
        const Active = TRUE
        const MaxAge = 30
        const RECYCLE_BIN = &Ha&

```
    checked = 0
    deleted = 0

    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(RECYCLE_BIN)
    Set colItems = objFolder.Items

    For Each objItem  In colItems
            Checked = Checked + 1
            dateStr = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objItem, 2) 'the deletion date per file/folder
            dateArr = Split(dateStr, " ")
            dateDeleted = cDate(dateArr(0))
            If DateDiff("D", dateDeleted, Now()) > MaxAge Then
                    If objItem.Type = "File Folder" Then
                            Deleted = Deleted + 1
                            objFso.DeleteFolder(objItem.Path)
                    Else
                            Deleted = Deleted + 1
                            objFso.DeleteFile(objItem.Path)
                    End If
            End If
    Next
    if Active then verb = " file(s) deleted" Else verb = " file(s) would be deleted"
    WScript.Echo Checked & " file(s) checked, " & Deleted & verb
```

but again this does not work and creates a mismatch error on the cDate.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks related to the string encoding that's returned from `GetDetailsOf()`. I didn't spend a lot of time trying to figure out what it was. Instead, I just stripped out any non-date characters by using a regex. Here's an example:

```
Dim re
Set re = New RegExp
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = "[^/0-9]"    ' Assuming regional settings use "/" for separator

d = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objItem, 2)

' Split by space char and return first element to get date only...
d = Split(d, " ")(0)

' Remove any non-date chars...
d = re.Replace(d, "")

MsgBox DateDiff("d", d, Date)    ' Works!
```

Of course, you could combine everything into a single statement:

```
d = re.Replace(Split(objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objItem, 2), " ")(0), "")
```

Comment: oh dude!! thanks so much for this! I didn't think to use regexing to solve the problem! to be honest I don't exactly know what the problem was because I'm new to vbscript. Saved me from a tone of hours getting nowhere for a simple script

Comment: It's no problem. Glad I could help!